# blending two UIImages yields unexpected results

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage

i am blending two images together and use a slider to modify the alpha value. they are the original picture and a filtered one. i use the blending to control the intensity of my filter. this is the blend function:

```
+ (UIImage*)blendImages:(UIImage*)back withTop:(UIImage*)front andAlpha:(float)alpha {    
    // images are same size
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(back.size.width, back.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, back.scale);

    // use existing opacity as is on background image
    [back drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    // Apply supplied opacity on foreground
    [front drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)
        blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:alpha];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

it all works okay, but with some alpha values (0.7f in this example) i get results like this one (not the highlighted area):

[image: result one]

if i do the same thing again later (i.e. same function, same alpha value) i get the result i want:

[image: result two]

if i keep going with filters, i sometimes have the highlights going off into magenta or cyan. the whole thing is completely unpredictable. however it is reproducible in some cases. has anyone been through this before? alternative ways to blend two images with alpha are very welcome as well. the blending of two images (iphone screen resolution) should take no more than a quarter of a second.

please help.

Comment: eventually, i switched over to GPUImage by brad larson to rid my app of all the malignance. brilliant software. check it out at github (https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) or on his website (http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2012/02/12/introducing-gpuimage-framework)

Answer (score 0):

The code looks roughly right.  Are you sure that the "scale" value coming in from the back image is correct?  It could be that is throwing off the gelding in some way, if the scale differs from the UIScreen scale.  I would try manually setting scale to 2.0 (if on a retina device) or 1.0 (if on non-retina) and see if the issue subsides.

Comment: thank you for looking at my problem. i just tried that, alas it produces the same results. also i observed all the values in the debugger to make sure all of the resolutions add up. like i mentioned, i am mainly puzzled because i get both results by calling the quoted function with the exact same objects and parameters twice. there must be something weird going on with the function call. thanks again for your time.

Comment: I was wondering if the scale value of the image changed between runs, so too bad that was not the problem.  I hate to suggest it, but perhaps you should just always run the blending twice as a workaround???

Comment: that works, however some other alpha values cause problems then. also it is way too slow.

Comment: Have you tried blending two single pixel images first, then the real size ones...

Comment: no i have not. maybe i'll try it, but only as a last resort. i'll try to update the sdk first.

Comment: just to clear this whole thing up. i have completely changed my code to incorporate brad larson's fantastic gpuimage libraries and am happier with those than ever. thank you for your concern with my problem